# .NET core project missing 4.5+ target frameworks in drop down

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have a .NET core class library.  I need to target the 4.5.2 framework.  In 'Project Properties' I see a Target framework drop down with two frameworks: .NETCoreApp 1.0 and .NETCoreApp 1.1 (selected).  There are no other options.

I click the "Install other frameworks..." option and a web page opens that tells me that 4.5.2 is Included with Visual Studio 2017.  In addition, I know I must have 4.5.2 because other projects use it (and it shows in the target framework dropdown of the other non-core projects).  I installed 4.5.2 again anyway and it's still not in the drop down.

Is there something else I need to do so a core project can target 4.5.2?

Comment: They try to keep things simple and you should follow. If you do want to write a class library for .NET Core and .NET Framework, choose .NET Standard Class Library project type.

Answer (score 0):

This is an useful link that will help solve your issue.

https://jonhilton.net/2017/03/14/use-asp-net-core-1-1-with-net-4-without-visual-studio/